# Debian 8 VPS - a reboot regenerates host ssh keys

Tags: debian, sshd, reboot

I have problem, because each reboot of my Debian 8 is generating new host RSA keys. How to avoid this?

Comment: No, this is VPS.

Comment: Why do you think it does? What is in the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I know why this happens. In /etc/rc.local is script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
rm -f etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t dsa -N '' -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t rsa1 -N '' -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -N '' -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -N '' -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
systemctl restart ssh

DHCP6CCTLKEY=/etc/wide-dhcpv6/dhcp6cctlkey

# The key mustn\'t be world readable
umask 066

echo "Generating ${DHCP6CCTLKEY}..." >&2
dd if=/dev/random bs=32 count=1 2>/dev/null |   uuencode -m ${DHCP6CCTLKEY} | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 > ${DHCP6CCTLKEY}

umask 022
mv -f /etc/rc.local.orig /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: But why is this the default?